# Recursive Dictionary for Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
index   0   1   2
    0   a   a   0.2
    1   a   a   0.4
    0   a   b   0.4
    1   a   b   0.7
```

What I want is to create a dictionary to access column `2` easily via columns `0` and `1`, looking like this:

```
{(a, a): pd.Series(data=[0.2, 0.4], index=[0, 1]),
 (a, b): pd.Series(data=[0.4, 0.7], index=[0, 1])}
```

How could you make this transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby([0,1]).agg(list).to_dict('index')

{('a', 'a'): {'index': [0, 1], '2': [0.2, 0.4]},
 ('a', 'b'): {'index': [0, 1], '2': [0.4, 0.7]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert groupby object to dictionaries for dict of Series:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby([0,1])[2]))
```

Or use dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {k: v[2] for k, v in df.groupby([0,1])}
```

---

```
print (d[('a','a')])
0    0.2
1    0.4
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```